# Can't deploy Java Melody with my ear-file on WAS8.0

Tags: deployment, ear, websphere-8, java-melody

I try to use [Java Melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) to monitor my application which has to run on a Websphere 8.0 Application server.

I followed the steps described in the [Advanced User Guide](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#Setup_in_an_ear_file) 
The resulting ear can be deployed just fine on a local Glassfish, that I use for development.

But when I deploy it on our WAS I get

```
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/home/wasweb/wastools/deploy.py"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: com.ibm.ws.management.application.dfltbndngs.BindingError: could not bind resource refs [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ArchiveWrappedException]
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ArchiveWrappedException: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ArchiveWrappedException
```

And the application does not get deployed/started

Without Java Melody the application deploys just fine.

Since tried to deploy the ear even without the necessary changes to the web.xml basically the only cause I can imagine is either: WAS can't handle the application.xml or it can't handle the melody and jrobin jars in the ear. But I have no idea how to debug this.

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you check the PROFILE_HOME/logs/wsadmin.traceout for a better error message?

Comment: No, got sidetracked by other issues. But eventually it will reapear on the top of my todo list.

Comment: I had a similar problem (but without Melody, so this is not an answer) and to me the problem was that a module was in the application.xml that had no deployment descripter. The logs in SystemOut.log pointed in the right direction.